# Problems using jquery.knob dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I dynamically load JS - files:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(
        $.getScript("./setup/js/jquery.knob.js"),
        $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        })
    ).done(function () {
        $(function ($) {
            $(".knob").knob({});
        });
    });
});
```

In the source I get the error

```
"Object [object Object] has no method 'knob' "
```

When I load the sources inside the page using  everything works fine, but I have to wrap the whole page into a JS-File

No other error messages in the console, especially no security-related error messages

(update) When I just copy/paste the complete knob-source into my .JS it works, but of course this is not my preferred solution

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Other than the fact that you are missing a closing `})`, I cannot reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nVA3A/

Comment: Thats weird. The code is inside a chrome extension. Perhaps thats the cause?